# set button visibility in code behind aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

How can I set in my button_Click event, visibility of button in gridView to false?
All the time it give me an error:Compilation Error

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'btnTest' does not exist in the current context

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button189" OnClick="Button189_Click" runat="server" Text="odzemi svez vrganj" />

                        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" CommandName="odzemi" CssClass="button2" OnClick="btnTest_Click" Text="-" Width="100px" Font-Bold="True" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Following is my button event from where i want to hide button inside gridview.

```
 protected void Button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     btnTest.Visible = true;
     Button189.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: Your btnTest is repeated in each row in gridview with asp generated id you need to use findcontrol on each row and then set its visibility to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the gridview rows and find the control

```
  foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
   {
     if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         var control =  ((Button)row.FindControl("btnTest"));
         if (control != NULL)
         {
             ((Button)control).Visible = false;
         }  
      }          
  }
```

Comment: now isn't give me an error, but the button is still visible :(

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to set button visible  property to **True** or **False** . The Button in gridview which will be clicked will act as sender. Doing so will give you the row id where the button is fired from and then you can find other controls and set your desired property on that particular row.

```
protected void Button189_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Button Btn = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gvRow = Btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int rowId = gvRow.RowIndex;
        Button Button189 = GridView2.Rows[rowId].FindControl("Button189") as Button;
        Button btnTest = GridView2.Rows[rowId].FindControl("btnTest") as Button;
        Button189.Visible = false;
        btnTest.Visible = true;
 }
```

Comment: You can cast `sender` as `Button189` .

Comment: but protected void Button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } is outside of gidview

Comment: @Suprabhat give error   int rowId = gvRow.RowIndex; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Buba  Couldn't understood what u said above "protected void...is outside of gidview". Your both buttons are inside gridview and button event will be generated from gruidview. Just give it a try, i have done  such kind of thing many times in my project. If, it doesn't work lets us know here. We can resolve it in other ways.

Comment: It's ok, work..i understood you! But i want to set button189 to false from another button which is NOT  in gridview.

Comment: @Buba  Sorry, I misunderstood your question please accept Coder of Code answer as correct answer because you forgot to replace ((Button)row.FindControl("btnTest")) to ((Button)row.FindControl("Button189"))  as you require to hide Button189 not btnTest. Therefore the button was still visible, his given code is working perfectly  :)

Comment: in this code, how to know in which row will be hidden btnTest, becouse that button is generated in every row

Comment: @buba In that case every row must have some unique identifier maybe a name or a number which you can identify at runtime and hide that particular control by comparing with the unique identifier. Only way to achieve hiding button row by row is by generating events from gridview which i have done above.

Comment: I have labels with different value, how to set up there in row that unique label value